# JVM not able validate the SSL certificate

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, jvm

I have a Client-Server model Application. The server is running in AWS cloud with ALB SSL Enabled. All my server request are filtered by the ALB.

When I access my server using Chrome web browser all is good with no issues. The browser is  able to validate the certificate. But JVM  is throwing  the below error:

> Error Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path
> building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

This issue not in all the Windows machine select machine which having VPN installed.

How I can Debug this issue?

Am using Java 1.8 version

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ). Use ​`-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` to get more debug information.

Comment: You should post the full stack trace. What specific SSL connection is failing? Is it failing when it connects to a database server or something?

Answer (score -4):

okay,you can choice 1.8 different branch version,by reading jdk sorce code that is bug.

Comment: What do you mean? Would you please elaborate?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).